# Custom form field in views

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to create a custom field for a view in Drupal 8 which allows to perform an action  without changing the page (link). I guess I have to create a form inside that custom field but I do not know how to achieve it.

Any idea on how to do it or other alternative without redirecting to a route?

The view will be a list of custom entities and I need a button for each of the lines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it by following this steps:

- I created a view custom field (generate:plugin:views:field with
  drupal console)
- I created a form (generate:form)

Then, in the view custom field render function return the form:

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\test_module\Form\TestForm', $values->_entity->ID());
return $form;
```

It's important to notice that **an incremental (dynamic) formId is needed for things to work properly**. I did that by creating a static variable and a __construct() method as follows:

```
protected static $instanceId;

public function getFormId() {
  return 'my_form_id_' . self::$instanceId;
}

public function __construct(){
  if (empty(self::$instanceId)) {
    self::$instanceId = 1;
  }
  else {
    self::$instanceId++;
  }
}
```